# cocos2d & CAShapeLayer objects

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cashapelayer

My class X is interited from CCLayer.

```
@interface X : CCLayer
```

Then in X, I added an instance variable of type CAShapeLayer.

```
CAShapeLayer *_Circle
```

I drew the Circle using UIBezierPath. Now if I try to add _circle to self, it gives me error:

```
[self addChild:_Circle];
```

> [CAShapeLayer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x916f7f0 
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CAShapeLayer tag]:
>   unrecognized.

I also tried typecasting _Circle to (CCNode*) or (CCSprite*) but nothing helped.

Please advise.

Comment: Anyone knows how to add CAShapeLayer chile object to CCLayer parent object?